# Keep user logged in when app is closed - Android Studio - MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have create an App where a User list for a group is already placed in a database on MySQL, the Usernames, passwords and variables assigned to them are already uploaded.

Below is the login activity that allows a user to log in and go to their own user area (There is a loginrequest class also that brings the params over).

What I need assistance with is making the application stay logged in until logout for that user even when they have closed the app.

Also will this if possible allow me to send user notifications when the app is closed to individual users?

thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

    //Register Here button
    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    //Login Button
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Taking the username and password and converting it to a string
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //Taking the JSONObject from the 000webhost database

                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        //If the response is successful ie is there a username and password that match
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success){
                            //Gather the information below
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            int var1 = jsonResponse.getInt("var1");
                            int var2 = jsonResponse.getInt("var2");
                            int var3 = jsonResponse.getInt("var3");
                            int var4 = jsonResponse.getInt("var4");



                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("var1", var1);
                            intent.putExtra("var2", var2);
                            intent.putExtra("var3", var3);
                            intent.putExtra("var4", var4);
                            intent.putExtra("password", password);

                            //Start the User Area Activity

                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);




                        }else{

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };



            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: save some value in `SharedPreferences` and check for it on app start!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences, to resolve your problem.

**Use this to verify if the user has "session" started or not**

```
      private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;    

    sharedpreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
                    String login = sharedpreferences.getString("LOGIN", null);


                    if (login != null) {
         //put your code if user is logged. For example, go to another activity
        }else {

// to go login activity
}
```

**Use this to set the "session" when click on login button**

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("LOGIN", newUser.getEmail_user());
                        editor.commit
```

**Use this on Logout Button**

```
 Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.remove("LOGIN"); 
                    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Every time I attempt to add this to my Login Activity which is the launch activity for me App I just get a white screen.
I get no errors in the Gradle Build.

Comment: sorry for answer just now...  you can solve white screen problem?

Comment: I fixed this issue I just forgot to set one String as final when I wanted to get the string.